# Oracle sql query to group consecutive records by date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

With the below sample data, I am trying to group record with same rate.

```
   id   start_date              end_date                rate
  -----------------------------------------------------------------

    1   01/01/2017 12:00:00 am  01/01/2017 12:00:00 am  300
    1   02/01/2017 12:00:00 am  02/01/2017 12:00:00 am  300
    1   03/01/2017 12:00:00 am  03/01/2017 12:00:00 am  300
    1   04/01/2017 12:00:00 am  04/01/2017 12:00:00 am  1000
    1   05/01/2017 12:00:00 am  05/01/2017 12:00:00 am  500
    1   06/01/2017 12:00:00 am  06/01/2017 12:00:00 am  500
    1   07/01/2017 12:00:00 am  07/01/2017 12:00:00 am  1000
    1   08/01/2017 12:00:00 am  08/01/2017 12:00:00 am  1000
    1   09/01/2017 12:00:00 am  09/01/2017 12:00:00 am  300
```

What I've tried :

```
select distinct id, mn_date, mx_date,rate
from (
    select id, min(start_date) over (partition by grp order by start_date) mn_date,
    max(end_date) over(partition by grp order by start_date desc) mx_date, rate
    from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by id order by start_date) -row_number() over(partition by rate order by start_date)grp
    from t
        )
    )
order by mn_date;
```

Output :

```
id  mn_date                 mx_date                 rate
--------------------------------------------------------
1   01/01/2017 12:00:00 am  03/01/2017 12:00:00 am  300
1   04/01/2017 12:00:00 am  04/01/2017 12:00:00 am  1000
1   05/01/2017 12:00:00 am  06/01/2017 12:00:00 am  500
1   07/01/2017 12:00:00 am  09/01/2017 12:00:00 am  300
1   07/01/2017 12:00:00 am  09/01/2017 12:00:00 am  1000
```

Desired Output:

```
id  mn_date                 mx_date                 rate
--------------------------------------------------------
1   01/01/2017 12:00:00 am  03/01/2017 12:00:00 am 300
1   04/01/2017 12:00:00 am  04/01/2017 12:00:00 am 1000
1   05/01/2017 12:00:00 am  06/01/2017 12:00:00 am 500
1   07/01/2017 12:00:00 am  08/01/2017 12:00:00 am 1000
1   09/01/2017 12:00:00 am  09/01/2017 12:00:00 am 300
```

Final result to group by consecutive dates:  (Thanks to Gordon )

```
select id, min(start_date), max(end_date), rate
from (
select id, start_date, end_date, rate, seqnum_i-seqnum_ir grp, sum(x) over(partition by id order by start_date) grp1
from (
select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by start_date) as seqnum_i,
             row_number() over (partition by id, rate order by start_date) as seqnum_ir,
             case when LEAD(start_date) over (partition by id order by start_date)= end_date + 1 
             then 0 
             else 1
             end x
from t
)
)
group by id, grp+grp1, rate
order by min(start_date);
```

Comment: how do you want to group the data? What is the difference between output and desired output? what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we can just use `start_date` to identify the adjacent records (i.e., there are no gaps), then you can use the difference of row numbers approach:

```
select id, min(start_date) as mn_date, max(end_date) as mx_date, rate
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by start_date) as seqnum_i,
             row_number() over (partition by id, rate order by start_date) as seqnum_ir
      from t
     ) t
group by id (seqnum_i - seqnum_ir), rate;
```

To see how this works, look at the results of the subquery.  You should be able to "see" how the difference of the two row numbers defines the groups of adjacent records with the same rate.

Comment: Thanks Gordon:), The query I have tried first time also was based on your input in another thread. Thanks for the new solution.

Comment: Could you suggest the change, If I want to make the above records as a group for consecutive date range? Suppose I have an extra entry with existing list with start_date & end_date as (11/01/2017 to 13/01/2017) respectively with rate 300. And the query should result in new row as it is not a consecutive date? I' ve tried with lead() but failed to get the expected result. And one more entry (15/01/2017 & 15/01/2017) , rate 300.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the last value wasn't being grouped correctly as the calculation of X wasn't handling the NULL return, so I changed it to this:

```
          ,CASE
               WHEN LEAD (start_date)
                       OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY start_date)
                       IS NULL
               THEN
                  0
               WHEN LEAD (start_date)
                       OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY start_date) =
                       end_date + 1
               THEN
                  0
               ELSE
                  1
            END
               x
```