# Is there way to build logic to get one initial date of multiple entries of leaves extended further

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
Emp_no | from_date  | To_date   | Initial_date
-------+------------+-----------+-------------
234    | 01-Dec-18  | 10-Dec-18 | 01-Dec-18     
234    | 11-Dec-18  | 05-Jan-19 | 01-Dec-18     
234    | 06-Jan-19  | 20-Jan-19 | 01-Dec-18     
234    | 21-Jan-19  | 25-Jan-19 | 01-Dec-18
```

I just want to get the initial date of further extended leaves as all the entries will be treated as one initial date. How can I get the above mentioned result with column `Initial_date`?

This is to add an extra functionality to calculate the total authorized or earned leave of Service in the leave management software, as in each month 4 leaves has been earned by employees with the following conditions:

1. 16 days attendance is necessary in a month to earn the leaves.
2. If leave connects two months so the earning of one of the month will be 
   lost and the earning of other month depends on the 1st condition of 16 days attendance.

So I just want to create a logic to sort out these kinds of leave which has been taken and further extended to more days which results multiple entries of continued leaves.

Comment: To clarify: You consider a date as an initial date, from the set of entries, only when this is a series of consecutive leaves (i.e. the `from_date` of an entry is equal to `To_date` of another plus one) of that same employee. If that's so, you may find this question interesting: [Oracle sql query to group consecutive records by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46298871)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your requirements, but let's try:

```
select emp_no, from_date, to_date, level lvl,
       connect_by_root(from_date) initial_date
  from tbl t1
  start with 
    not exists (
      select 1 
        from tbl t2 
        where t1.emp_no = t2.emp_no and t1.from_date = t2.to_date + 1)
  connect by emp_no = prior emp_no and from_date = prior to_date + 1
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f7809892601a0baf9d832b4229dfce5d)</sup>**

Using these sample data:

```
with tbl(emp_no, from_date, to_date) as (
    select 234, date '2018-12-01', date '2018-12-10' from dual union all
    select 234, date '2018-12-11', date '2019-01-05' from dual union all
    select 234, date '2019-01-06', date '2019-01-20' from dual union all
    select 234, date '2019-01-21', date '2019-01-25' from dual union all
    -- not continuous dates 
    select 234, date '2019-03-10', date '2019-03-17' from dual union all 
    select 234, date '2019-03-18', date '2019-03-25' from dual union all 
    -- other emp_no
    select 407, date '2018-12-15', date '2019-01-07' from dual )
```

... we get this result:

```
EMP_NO FROM_DATE   TO_DATE            LVL INITIAL_DATE
------ ----------- ----------- ---------- ------------
   234 2018-12-01  2018-12-10           1 2018-12-01
   234 2018-12-11  2019-01-05           2 2018-12-01
   234 2019-01-06  2019-01-20           3 2018-12-01
   234 2019-01-21  2019-01-25           4 2018-12-01
   234 2019-03-10  2019-03-17           1 2019-03-10
   234 2019-03-18  2019-03-25           2 2019-03-10
   407 2018-12-15  2019-01-07           1 2018-12-15
```

If this is not what you needed please edit your question and show required output matching more complicated sample data (for instance my sample above).

Explanation: Hieriarchical query (`connect by`) finds for every `emp_no` dates which are not continuous and starting from these points attaches next continuous rows. Operator `connect_by_root` is used to present `initial_date`.

Comment: The problem has been solved by your help thank you so much bro :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of

```
select emp_id, from_date, to_date, (select min(from_date) 
                                    from TABLE_NAME T1 
                                    where t1.emp_id = t.emp_id) as inital_date
from TABLE_NAME T
where emp_id = 234;
```

Comment: Dear shaun this query will add a minimam date of all  entries of individual, but we actually need the same initail date of those leave which is extended further like in table above  rather then minimam of all entries.