# create date range from day based data

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

i have following source data...

```
id     date     value
1      01.08.22 a
1      02.08.22 a
1      03.08.22 a
1      04.08.22 b
1      05.08.22 b
1      06.08.22 a
1      07.08.22 a
2      01.08.22 a
2      02.08.22 a
2      03.08.22 c
2      04.08.22 a
2      05.08.22 a
```

and i would like to have the following output...

```
id     date_from     date_until    value
1      01.08.22      03.08.22      a
1      04.08.22      05.08.22      b
1      06.08.22      07.08.22      a
2      01.08.22      02.08.22      a     
2      03.08.22      03.08.22      c
2      04.08.22      05.08.22      a
```

Is this possible with Oracle SQL? Which functions do I need for this?

Comment: I will change the example source data because the first where wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle query group by consecutive value and get start date and end date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58487031/oracle-query-group-by-consecutive-value-and-get-start-date-and-end-date)

Comment: Not really, no. Because the value can be any string for me and not a number which is being summed up.

Comment: It is not about summation, but aggregation: use `max/min/whatever` to select a single value per group. The core part is a solution for gaps and islands problem using `row_number`, not an actual computation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the link provided by @astentx, try this solution:

```
SELECT 
    id, MIN("date") AS date_from, MAX("date") AS date_until, MAX(value) AS value
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t1.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "date") -
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id, value ORDER BY "date") AS rn
    FROM yourtable t1
) 
GROUP BY id, rn
```

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=385f2a14d0fb2f2d3435eac84c6bc38e)

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE (id, dateD,valueD)
AS
(
   SELECT 1,    TO_DATE('01.08.22','DD.MM.YY'), 'a' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 1,     TO_DATE('02.08.22','DD.MM.YY'), 'a'FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 1,     TO_DATE('03.08.22','DD.MM.YY'), 'a'FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 1,     TO_DATE('04.08.22','DD.MM.YY'), 'b'FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 1,     TO_DATE('05.08.22','DD.MM.YY'), 'b'FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 2,     TO_DATE('01.08.22','DD.MM.YY'), 'a'FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 2,     TO_DATE('02.08.22','DD.MM.YY'), 'a'FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 2,     TO_DATE('03.08.22','DD.MM.YY'), 'c'FROM DUAL
)
 SELECT C.ID,C.VALUED,MIN(C.DATED)AS MIN_DATE,MAX(C.DATED)AS MAX_DATE
 FROM CTE C
 GROUP BY C.ID,C.VALUED
 ORDER BY C.ID
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=47c87d60445ce262cd371177e31d5d63

Comment: Okay, that works for the example. 
But what happens if now for the ID "1" the value changes back to "a" and i would to have a "new" period as output. Then it doesn't work anymore or?

Comment: Quite possible.But then could you please provide more completed dataset and desired output to be able to test different dolutions

Comment: Sorry that the first data was not extensive enough. I have adjusted the example data again.